# Reverse Climb a Child/Parent Tree in Angular - Observable vs Promise

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular2-observables

Let us say we have a data structure that is hierarchical - ie, each item may have one or more children and the children linked through a parent Id.

Lets say we also want to loop through from the current group all the way to the parent to get the structure.

While most of the Angular documentation seems to refer to using Observables, in a While Loop (ie while parentId != undefined), we have the issue that the while loop may continue several times because we're subscribing to the output of an observable which we don't get until the observable is fulfilled.

```
while (childGroup.parentGroupId !== undefined) {
  this.groupsService.getGroup(childGroup.parentGroupId).subscribe(group => {
    groupHierarchy.unshift(group);
    childGroup = group;
  });
}
```

So then we may need to do a combineLatest so we can process all the observables together.

```
while (childGroup.parentGroupId !== undefined) {
  observables.push(this.groupsService.getGroup(childGroup.parentGroupId))
}

combineLatest(observables).subscribe( data => { // Process Here });
```

I have used this in a couple of other samples when I have a list of data to collect, but I was wondering if there's a reason why we don't use Promise instead of Observable?:

```
this.groupsService.getGroup2(childGroup.parentGroupId).then(group => { groupHierarchy.unshift(group); childGroup = group; } )
```

Indeed I might need to use this anyhow unless you can think of another solution. I have to wait to get the current node's parent before I work out what the next parent is.

Your thoughts appreciated.